# GXT model.get() returns wrong type of instance

Tags: gwt, casting, gxt

in my app i'm using gwt 2.5.0 and gxt 2.2.5. So, I have my ColumnConfig column with this renderer:

```java
column.setRenderer(new GridCellRenderer() {

            @Override
            public Text render(ModelData model, String property, ColumnData config, int rowIndex, int colIndex, ListStore listStore, Grid grid) {
                List<AccountGroupDto> accountGroups  = model.get(property);
                // some stuff here

                return groupsText;
            }
        });
```

But when I try to do something with my list emenetns, I get some kind of type casting error. I used a debugger and it appears that type of my list elements is `com.example.core.application.api.BeanModel_com_example_core_application_api_AccountGroupDto` and it can't be cast to `com.example.core.application.api.AccountGroupDto`, which it should be.

This error appeared when i've upgraded gwt from 1.7 and gxt from 2.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Add the type to your GridCellRenderer (acording to your error I asume you are using BeanModel) so use this type:

```
column.setRenderer(new GridCellRenderer<BeanModel>() {

            @Override
            public Object render(BeanModel model, String property, ColumnData config, int rowIndex, int colIndex, ListStore<BeanModel> store, Grid<BeanModel> grid) {
                // ...
```

The model returned by the render event its a BeanModel, now, to obtain the original element use the *.getBean* property of the model.

```
OriginalObjectType myObj = model.getBean();
```

now you can get your object from myObj:

```
List<AccountGroupDto> accountGroups  = myObj.get(property);
```

Hope this helps.